# Ionic auth with express,passport and mongoose

Tags: javascript, authentication, express, mongoose, ionic-framework

I want to create an authentication app with ionic.I want to use ionic as client and express,passport and mongoose for backend.I've see some examples but their code are a little bit hard to understand.I just want  a simple working example.Thanks for any help or advice!